# Lock pinned taskbar items so they can't be rearranged

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, pinning

Occasionally I find that I've accidentally rearranged the pinned icons on my taskbar by dragging them out of order, which is mildly annoying. The somewhat obvious *Lock the taskbar* option doesn't affect items, only the taskbar itself.

Is there some way to prevent the items from being moved? Registry tweaks, external programs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) (suggested in several other questions about taskbar customization) offers a solution, but it's not that obvious.

1. Install and run 7+ Taskbar Tweaker.
2. The option isn't available in the main window. Instead, go to the system tray and right-click the 7TT tray icon. Select *Advanced options*.
3. What you're looking for is the aptly named `disable_items_drag` setting. Double-click the *Data* field (which is 0 by default) and change it to 1.
4. You can no longer accidentally move your pinned items.

   - However, you can still reorder open windows using right click if you check the *Drag within/between groups using right mouse button* option in the main window.